# jQuery Validate plugin, how to stop form submit with an external handler

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, form-submit

I have a global script to validate forms with jqueryvalidation:

```
$("form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      $("body").append("<p>validate</p>");
      form.submit();
    }
  });
```

In a particular form I need to add another "second" handler to this form:

```
 $("#myform").submit(function(){
    $("body").append("<p>other handler</p>");
    return false;
  });
```

Why the  `return false;` of the second handler doesn't block the form submit?
I also tried with preventDefault and stopProparation but it doesn't work.

https://jsfiddle.net/brj7ttdn/5/

Comment: i can't see this situation on your jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry, my fiddle was updated only for my session, now I update the link to last version.

Comment: @Tobia let me know if my answer helps you

Comment: I think it can be a solution, but that way I have to change the common validate script of the whole application and not only the particulare one. This is becase I want to wait if there is another good solution only using jquery event handling. For what I know the "return false" of the second method should prevent the form submit....

Comment: I don't believe a solution is possible as the plugin is already capturing and handling the `submit` event.

Comment: @Sparky For example I can add many click events to <a> element, they are fired one after the other and if someone in the chain flags "stopPropagation" the chais is broken and the final link is not reached. Is not possibile to do the same for a submit?

Comment: So what's wrong with the workaround posted here?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/36543695/594235

Comment: Ok they unbind the submit from the validator, this can be a solution! But is not possibile to simply stop the event propagation like other events?

Comment: There is only one `submit` event that fires when the form submits and you're trying to capture that in two places.  This does not have anything to do with propagation since nothing is bubbling up the DOM tree.  See: https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108833/discussion-between-tobia-and-sparky).

Answer (score 1):

Could you perhaps remove the global submithandler and only let the specific one run? Like this:

```
$(function(){

$("form").validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {
     $("body").append("<p>validate</p>");
     form.submit();
   }
});

$('#myform').off('submit')

$("#myform").submit(function(e){
   $("body").append("<p>validate</p>");
   $("body").append("<p>other handler</p>");
     e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

You would have to call the validation from the other handler as well, but that might not be too painful, just make a `form.valid()` call

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brj7ttdn/13/)** And the code is as below.

```
$(function() {

  $("form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      $("body").append("<p>validate</p>");

      if ($(form).data('has-customSubmit-event') === true) {
        $(form).trigger('customSubmit'); // trigger your custom submit.
      } else {
        form.submit();
      }
    }
  });

  $('#myform').data('has-customSubmit-event', true); // add a pointer to say there is a custom handler for this form, 

  $("#myform").on('customSubmit', function(e) { 
    $("body").append("<p>other handler</p>");    
     //$(this).submit(); // if you want to submit this form.
  });

});
```

The idea is to add a pointer saying for this form if its valid don't do the plugin's submit ie `form.submit();` but run your custom logic and then either submit or dont submit.

The pointer I am talking about is this

`$('#myform').data('has-customSubmit-event', true);`

Now in the plugin submit handler we can have a if check saying if this form has a custom handler to execute then do it, else submit the form.

```
if ($(form).data('has-customSubmit-event') === true) {
   $(form).trigger('customSubmit'); // trigger your custom submit.
} else {
     form.submit();
}
```

---

Also the way you are adding the validation plugin `$("form").validate({..` like this. So what I found out was this will trigger the submit handler event for only the first form(Not sure why, **[Fiddle With Issue](https://jsfiddle.net/brj7ttdn/10/)**).

So to fix it use a `each()` feature to loop through all the forms and bind the plugin individually, **[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brj7ttdn/11/)**

Comment: I thought about this solution, the main problem is that I need to run the second handler only if the form is validater, so I would prefer the oppositr order if I can control event bubbling.

Comment: This is not good designed flow. If you wanna do something like that, write an validation function and call it, your design make some risk for sequence of processes.

Comment: @Tobia I updated my answer, have a check if this works for you.

Comment: @cuonghoang I am not sure of what you meant by `not good designed flow` anyways I have updated my answer to a new logic, So you can remove that comment

Comment: @Reddy: i'm sorry for make you confusing, my comment is for Tobia.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try the preventDefault() properly like below:

```
$(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(event){
    $("body").append("<p>other handler</p>");
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Check the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjaykumarns/brj7ttdn/3/).

Comment: You fiddle works because you removed the first validation handler. In my case I have 2 handler, the first one (global of the main project and I cannot change it) and my custom one to a single form.

Comment: Sorry, my fiddle was updated only for my session, now I update the link to last version and now I think you can understand my situation.

Answer (score -1):

Disable your button click event, the form submit will disable too.
Change

```
$("#myform").submit(function(e){
```

to

```
$("button").click(function(e){
```

If your form submit by press "ENTER", you must trigger keypress action and stop action submit with an script like:

```
$("input").on("keypress", function(e){
   var keypress;
   if(window.event) { // IE                    
      keypress= e.keyCode;
   } else if(e.which){ // Netscape/Firefox/Opera                   
      keypress= e.which;
   }
   if ( keypress == 13 ) {
      e.preventDefault();
   }
})
```

Comment: I want to disabled form submit also for "ENTER" press into a text input and so on... That button is there only for submit test purpose.

Comment: You submit form by javascript? Modify your script. If not, you needs click an button for submit your form.

Comment: @Tobia: cuz your validation using submit() action, no way to you for using an script trigger the same action to disable it. You need trigger an event before the submit() action called. So modify you script when form submit with "ENTER" / or click an button.

Comment: No, I don't need a click to submit a form! try this: https://jsfiddle.net/tk7jbu29/ type enter on the text input!

Comment: i think you need an keypress event to handle the case. I updated my answer.